# Number of atoms in a tree

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I don't understand the following paragraph:

> (COUNT-ATOMS ’(A (B) C)) should return five.
>
> A, B, and C and two NILs in the tree.
>
> Write a function COUNT-ATOMS that returns the number of atoms in a tree.

I tried this:

```
(defun count-atoms(l)
  (cond
    ((null l) 0)
    (t (+ (cond
            ((atom (car l)) 1)
            (t 0))
          (count-atoms (cdr l))))))
```

However, `(COUNT-ATOMS '(A (B) C))` return 2.

How should I do to return 5 instead?

Could you explain in more details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wanted to build `(a (b) c)` at runtime, using only `cons` and `quote`, you would write:

```
(cons 'a                      
      (cons (cons 'b nil)     
            (cons 'c nil)))
```

There are 5 atoms (a, b, c and two nil) in the tree being built. In practice you could use a simpler notation, like `(list 'a (list 'b) 'c)`.

In your function, you do not recurse into the CARS of your trees, only the CDRS. Also, when the CAR is not an atom, like when you encounter `(B)`, you add zero (the default clause in the second `cond`) *(edit. As kmkaplan noted, you also count zero for nil, first cond)*.

A simple solution is this, based on [`typecase`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_tpcase.htm):

```
(defun count-atoms (form)
  (typecase form
    (atom 1)
    (cons (+ (count-atoms (car form))
             (count-atoms (cdr form))))))
```

- When you encounter an atom, the result is 1.
- When you have a cons cell, you sum the number of atoms in its car and cdr.

The `typecase` dispatches according to the type of its argument, here `form`. Each clause has the following syntax: `(type ...body...)`, where `type` is the name of a type and `...body...` one or more expressions (an implicit `progn`): the last value is the return value of the `typecase`, if the argument matches the type `type`.

The first clause `(atom 1)` says: *if form is an atom, return 1*. The following one, `(cons ...)` says: *else, if form is a cons cell, ...*. Here, [`atom`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw61/CLHS/Body/t_atom.htm) is the name of a type, which represents everything that is not a `cons`. Granted, once you know that something is not an atom, you know that it is necessarily a `cons`, and the second test is redundant. However, it is more readable and any decent compiler will optimize the second test away.

There is also a function named [`atom`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/f_atom.htm), which is a predicate that tests whether a value is an atom. That's why, when you write `(atom 1)` on its own, in the REPL, it returns T.

See also [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons) and Seibel's *Practical Common Lisp*'s [chapter about lists](http://gigamonkeys.com/book/they-called-it-lisp-for-a-reason-list-processing.html).

Comment: Answer Thank you.
But I have a question.                      What does (atom 1) mean here? (Atom 1) comes out of T.                 But how does it function like the number one?

Answer (score 2):

Your function has two problems. The first, neatly described in [coredump's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42312947/50902), is that your `COUNT-ATOMS` only recurse on the tail (`CDR`) and forget to recurse on the `CAR` element of your cons cell (`L`). Thus it fails to count the `B` atom.

The second problem is that you count `NIL` as `0` while it is an atom and should be counted as `1`.